# You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression from loop variable

Tags: powershell, loops

I have a small PowerShell script written by someone no longer around and I am trying to fix the error message, You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.  I understand that the loop doesn't like it when the value is null but I am not sure how to fix it.  Any thoughts?

```
$ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
Stop-Transcript | out-null
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
Start-Transcript -path C:\Temp\LastPass_Native_Messaging.txt -force


$preferences = "~\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\default\Preferences"

$preferences_json = Get-Content $preferences -raw | ConvertFrom-Json

$LASTPASS = $preferences_json.extensions.settings.hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd

foreach ($permission in "granted_permissions","active_permissions"){
    if (-not $LASTPASS.$permission.api.contains("nativeMessaging")) {
        write-host "Adding Permission"
        $LASTPASS.$permission.api += "nativeMessaging"
        $LASTPASS.$permission.api = $LASTPASS.$permission.api | sort
        }
        else { write-host "Permission found"}
}

$preferences_json | ConvertTo-Json  -depth 100 | set-content $preferences

Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: Please post the error message in full

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:2 char:9
+     if (-not $LASTPASS.$permission.api.contains("nativeMessaging")) {
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: Your code and your json file are misaligned - you’re trying to refer to a setting that doesn’t exist in the json and getting a ```$null``` value as a result, and then trying to access properties on it, which gives your error. Check all the expected values appear correctly in the json file. You can also try enabling “strict mode” at the top of your code to get a more specific error message - ```Set-StrictMode -Version “Latest”```